# Why doesn’t FieldExp (finite fields package) return a primitive element?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

1. Needs["FiniteFields`"]
2. fld=GF[2,3]
3. GF[2,{1,0,1,1}]
4. PowerListQ[fld]
5. True
6. pe=FieldExp[fld,1]
7. FieldExp[GF[2,{1,0,1,1}],1]

Comment: Could you elaborate your question a little bit? This is a bit blunt. I assume 3, 5, and 7 are outputs, but I get False at 5 instead of True.

Answer (score 1):

PowerListQ doesn't seem to accept variable substitution:

```
Needs["FiniteFields`"]
fld = GF[2, 3];
PowerListQ[fld] = True;
FieldExp[fld, 1]
PowerListQ[GF[2, 3]] = True;
FieldExp[fld, 1]
```

This returns

FieldExp[GF[2, {1, 0, 1, 1}], 1]

and

{0, 1, 0} 2

which is the expected answer.

I tried `PowerListQ[Evaluate[fld]] = True;` to no avail.

`ToExpression["PowerListQ[" <> ToString[fld] <> "]=True"]` works though.

I.e.

```
Needs["FiniteFields`"]
fld = GF[2, 3];
ToExpression["PowerListQ[" <> ToString[fld] <> "]=True"];
FieldExp[fld, 1]
```

yields {0, 1, 0} 2